# Local NuGet Package Web.config Transformation Only Works when Web.config is checked out

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I'm having trouble getting a custom NuGet package to do Web.config transformations.  I have a solution that has 2 different ASP.NET MVC web projects in it, each with separate Web.config files.  If I install the NuGet package into project 1, everything works great - the package is deployed and the Web.config is transformed using the Web.config.install.xdt.  However, if I install into project 2, my DLL is making it into the bin directory of the site, but the Web.config transformation isn't working.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Pro.  I've noticed though, that if I, prior to NuGet package install CHECK OUT the Web.config file, then the transformation works!  What is going on here?  Why is it necessary to check out the Web.config in one assembly but not another?  I've verified that the transformation does work via the Transformation Tester: https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/, and again it does work for project 1, just not project 2 unless I check out Web.config prior to install.  This is regardless of whether it's a fresh installation (no existing package in the "Packages" folder).

I've followed the NuGet does regarding transformations as closely as I can but no dice.  https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package

Here is my nuspec file.  I'm executing the command "nuget pack foo.csproj" in order to create the nupkg file, and the nupkg file looks right to me.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>Initial package created.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2016</copyright>
  </metadata>
  <files>
      <file src="Content\Web.config.install.xdt" target="content" />
      <file src="Content\Web.config.uninstall.xdt" target="content" />
  </files>
</package>
```

**Edit 1:** If I include an "Install.ps1" file with the NuGet package that performs the checkout of Web.config, then the Web.config transformations do seem to work **sometimes**.  This is a hacky unreliable workaround for what seems to be a bug in the NuGet installation, so if anyone has a fix, I'd love to see it.  Here's the contents of my hacky workaround Install.ps1 in case it helps anyone:

```
# This script is a workaround for Web.config transformations not taking effect.  It simply checks out Web.config which seems to correct the issue.
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
$projectFullName = $project.FullName

# build a path to the web.config using a regex replacement of the .csproj or .vbproj file name with Web.config (assumes they're in the same directory) 
$webConfig = $project.FullName -replace "\\([\w\.\d]+).\w{2}proj$", '\Web.config'
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" checkout $webConfig /noprompt
```